# The character does not stand still on the moving platform

Tags: unity, c#, physics, movement

I'm trying to create a simple platforming game. I have an animated platform moving in 2 opposite directions. I use this simple code to make the character move along with the platform while he is standing on it:

```
public class PlatformMoving : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) => other.transform.parent = transform;

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other) => other.transform.parent = null;
}
```

The character moves with `CharacterController.Move()`. When he stands still on the platform and movement vector equals to `Vector3.zero`, he moves in the direction opposite to the platform movement direction and can even fall down from the platform. But if I comment `charController.Move(movement)` line in a character motion script, everything works properly and the character does not move when he shouldn't do that. How to solve it?

Comment: Whenever the character lands on the platform, you want it to be a child of the platform?

Comment: @Sean Carey Actually, I didn't devise this method myself. I just saw it in YouTube video, and it worked properly.

Comment: Ok, but you have to understand the code. Can you post the YouTube video your following?

Comment: When doing movement, try moving character only if its `movement vector != Vector3.zero`. Like, try adding check `if (movement != Vector3.zero) { charController.Move(movement); }`

Comment: @Sean Carey That's it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rO19dA2jksk

Comment: @zergon321 did that answered your question? If yes, I will post it as answer.

Comment: @Tomas Švedas Yes, it did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the game developers hub, @**zergon321**!

Eventough, I've answered your question in comments, other people might be interested as well, so I'm putting the answer over here.

## The answer

Try checking if there's any movement input before applying it with `CharacterController`. So for example:

```
if(movement != Vector3.zero)
    charController.Move(movement);
```